# Изменение стиля при масштабирования браузера

Tags: html, css, css3

При изменения масштаба в браузере пропадает разделитель. Вот стиль:

```
width: 80% !important;
height: 1px !important;
background-color: #454a4d;
margin: auto;
```

Что сделать чтобы все корректно отображалось при масштабе *90%*? Высота становится в консоли *0.99* и полоса пропадает

Comment: Не ясна суть проблемы. Укажите пожалуйста более конкретно

Comment: В каком браузере тоже уточните.

Answer (score 0):

Увы, этого не добится. Все дело в том, что вы задали высоту в 1 пиксель. При масштабировании размеры уменьшаются, вместе с этим и размер пикселя уменьшается. Он становится меньше 1 пикселя, что делает его невидимым.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать эти стили:

```
width: 80% !important;
height: 0.07em !important;
background-color: #454a4d;
margin: auto;
```